# RabbitMQ Cannot connect the node in the cluster

Tags: rabbitmq

I have 2 nodes and I wanna make cluster out of it. I have installed RabbitMq.

Now I am stopping the rabbit app in 2nd node and trying to join cluster like below command:
sudo rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@rabbit1

But it throw below error

```
> DIAGNOSTICS
> ===========
> 
> attempted to contact: [rabbit@TELXRMQ01]
> 
> rabbit@rabbit1:   * unable to connect to epmd (port 4369) on rabbit1:
> nxdomain (non-existing domain)
> 
> 
> current node details:
> - node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-34@rabbit2'
> - home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
> - cookie hash: A85MNn8I1UhtrGozi+m/2g==
```

I am following this link : https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html
The errang cookie are same in both the node and 4369 port is open in both the node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to solved this problem.

Under RabbitMQ-3.6.9 and Erlang v8.3.3

- Correct and Same the file of `.erlang.cookie`

  ```
  chgrp rabbitmq /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
  chown rabbitmq /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
  chmod 400 /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
  ```
- Correct Hosts and Hostname

  - Hosts:

    ```
    cat /etc/hosts
    ```

    Result:

    ```
    127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
    ::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

    127.0.0.1     rabbitmq252
    192.168.4.249 rabbitmq249
    192.168.4.251 rabbitmq251
    192.168.4.252 rabbitmq252
    ```
  - Hostname:

    ```
    cat /etc/hostname
    ```

    Result:

    ```
    rabbitmq252
    ```
- Remove Cluster Node

  If the cluster already has the node, or status changed, or even some node `disagree` the other node. You can remove the node by the command:

  ```
  rabbitmqctl forget_cluster_node rabbit@rabbitmq252
  ```
- Clear Erlang Mnesia Database

  Under the file path of `/var/lib/rabbitmq/`, there are three files, like `erl_crash.dump  mnesia .erlang.cookie`.

  ```
  rm -rf /var/lib/rabbitmq/*
  ```
- Kill the process of rabbitmq

  ```
  ps aux|grep rabbitmq
  kill -9 remaining_process
  ```
- Reinstall RabbitMQ and Erlang

Anyway, if you encounter the problem, you should:

1. Read the status of service

   ```
   systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service -l
   # or
   service rabbitmq-server status
   # or
   journalctl -ex
   ```
2. Read the logs of service

   You can find the path under the status of service.

   ```
   cat /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@rabbitmq252.log
   # or
   cat /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@rabbitmq251-sasl.log
   ```
3. Read the status of ports

   ```
   netstat -ntlp
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding host in /etc/hosts file.

Comment: You should have marked CHENJIAN's answer as the correct one, with a note that you modified `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on the version so you have to use either `join_cluster` or `cluster`